# AltGr key not working, instead I have to use Ctrl+AltGr

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, rdp

I encountered this problem several times. I want to use a character accessible using the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> Key but for some reason it doesn't work. As if I didn't press the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key.

Usually I experience this in remote Desktop but not on my local machine. I think that this is triggered when doing a combination of those keys : <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>AltGr</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But I tried many of those combinations, and it didn't solve the problem.

I also figured out that I could access the characters I needed while doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd> instead of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Key</kbd>.

Comment: You are probably invoking the "change keyboard layout" hot key by mistake.

Comment: I'm not, i've checked for this one, and i'm sure Alt+Shift isn't involved. Anyway i only have one keyboard layout available, i disable the others.

Comment: I had this problem also when using UWP 10 emulator. Closing the emulator fixed it.

Comment: This happens to me when I have an open remote desktop window.

Comment: It only applies to me, and that is frequent, when I have a remote desktop window open and I am entering data on my local computer. Switching to the RDP and entering an Alt-Grp key fixes it

Answer (score 237, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem while writing my question !

Going into my remote session i tried two key combinations, and it solved the problem on my Desktop : <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (i don't know which one solved the problem though)

I tried to reproduce the problem, but i couldn't... but i'm almost sure it's one of the key combinations described in the question above (since i experienced this problem several times)

So it seems the problem comes from the use of RDP (windows7 and 8)

**Update 2017**: Problem occurs on Windows 10 aswell.

Comment: I've ran into the same issue. In my case, the culprit was indeed RDC (fullscreen mode). It's easy to reproduce : open a RD connection, but before the focus switches to the newly opened window, you switch focus back to your normal desktop using alt-tab... and voila, alt gr stopped working.

Comment: Related SuperUser question with answers: https://superuser.com/questions/602067/altgr-randomly-stops-working-on-windows-8

Comment: What exactly do you mean 'Going into my remote session'? When do press Alt+Enter?

Comment: @RuneJeppesen i mean bring the focus to your remote desktop window

Comment: it used to remote desktop, too, which was causing the problem all the time. At least, after clicking anywhere in the remote desktop (sometimes I had to try out all remote desktop sessions), the problem disappeared.

However, now I am experiencing the problem without having run remote desktop since the last system boot.

Comment: Can´t believe it.... I closed my running RDP and Alt Gr is working again. Thanks. Had this already a lot of times and THIS time I was really pissed ;-)

Comment: Had exactly the same issue, but wasn't running any RDP clients. However, I was connected to a Hyper-V image, and going into that session pressing Alt+Enter / Ctrl+Enter solved the problem in my host os (windows 10).

Comment: Didn't work for me (Windows 7). I had to switch my language to EN then switch back to FR.

Comment: Simply pressing and release Ctrl and Alt in turn in an editor on the remote host fixed it for me.

Comment: Many thanks.  I lost the AltGr on my local machine.  Closing all my remote desktop sessions restored it (Windows 10 1703).

Comment: My Alt Gr key suddenly stopped working (could not write @ with a Norwegian keyboard layout). I went to my remote connection, pressed Ctrl + Enter, which immediately solved the problem. How odd.

Comment: This fix also adds an unwanted US keyboard layout to the keyboard layout selection, which cannot be removed (and is not listed) in the language settings. Clearly a bug in Windows and/or Remote Desktop. There is no way this can be intended behavior.

Comment: Same for me. Problem was solved by closing the Remote Desktop windows!

Comment: After Closing "ngRemote" the issue in my case was solved

Comment: The issue happens when you open a RDP connection. Just bring the RDP window in foreground and press Alt + Enter .

The issue will disappear on all other windows too.

  |    Source: [How to Fix Alt Gr Key Not Working](https://tommynation.com/fix-alt-gr-key-working/#comment-2775211175).

Additional : https://superuser.com/questions/1149165/altgr-randomly-stops-working-on-windows-10